# Problem with Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following Batch file... When I run it in a normal command prompt - it runs as expected... Find that the server and destination exist, and does the backup and exits.

When I run this using the task scheduler - it sends the email that it cannot find the server, but still does the backup... Can anyone shed some light on this?

I'm running this on a Windows 7 machine.

```
:: Check for Network Connection...

ping <server> -n 1|find "Reply from"

if not errorlevel 0 goto NoNetwork
if not exist "\\<server>\SHARE\FOLDER" goto NoFolder

:: Do Stuff
robocopy "\\<server>\SHARE\FOLDER" "F:\Backups\<server>\FOLDER" *.* /E /SEC /COPYALL /PURGE /V /LOG:"c:\Logs\Backup.FILENAME.log" /ZB /R:5 /W:20 /TEE 
goto end

:NoNetwork
Echo Network Not found...
c:\Utils\bmail.exe -s MAILSERVER -t MAIL_TO -f MAIL_FROM -h -a "ERROR: Network Not Found..." -b "FILENAME - <server> Not Found"
goto end

:NoFolder
Echo Folder Not found...
c:\Utils\bmail.exe -s MAILSERVER -t MAIL_TO -f MAIL_FROM -h -a "ERROR: Folder Not Found..." -b "FILENAME - Folder Not Found"
goto end

:end
exit
```

Comment: try setting -n 1 to something bigger like -n 5 and try again

Comment: What's the output of the "ping" command?

Answer (score 0):

As to why the batch file might think the share is unavailable but robocopy can access it, perhaps robocopy has been configured with credentials for accessing that network share or at least a local user account, whereas the task scheduler is running under a different account?

As to why the call to robocopy would ever get made in this script... well, I have no idea.